# ERROR N code: "auth/internal-error" message: "Photo URL too long." Prototype N

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to upadate firebase profile picture using cordova camera plugin. But i have an error. Any idea please?

```
   async openLibrary() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 70,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };
   return await this.camera.getPicture(options);
  }


  async addPhoto() {
  const libraryImage = await this.openLibrary();
  this.photoCamera = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + libraryImage;
  }

   enregisterPseudoo() {

   this.user.updateProfile({
     displayName: this.pseudo,
     photoURL:(this.photoCamera)
     }).then(data => {
     this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage, {
       name: this.pseudo,
       photo:(this.photoCamera),
       });
     });
       }
```

the url is too long any idea please ?

Comment: Can you add what is the error?

Comment: @yazantahhan  this is the error : ERROR
N

code: "auth/internal-error"

message: "Photo URL too long."

Prototype N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me. store the image in firebase storage then get the url

```
   const libraryImage = await this.openLibrary();
   this.photoCamera = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + libraryImage;
     let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
     this.avatarStgRef = firebase.storage().ref("pictures" + user.uid);
     this.avatarStgRef.putString(this.photoCamera, 'data_url'); 

    this.avatarStgRef.getDownloadURL().then(
    (url)=>{
   this.user.updateProfile({
   displayName: this.pseudo,
  photoURL: url
    }).then(data => {
    this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage, {
    name: this.pseudo,
    photo: url,
     });
      });
```

})

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works. In my case I had to do this: firebase.storage().ref('pictures/'+user.uid+'/avatar.jpg');

Answer (score 2):

The `photoURL` in a user's profile in Firebase Authentication must be a link to an existing image. You're trying to store the image as a data URL, which Firebase Authentication cannot handle.

So you'll have to upload the data to an image hosting service (e.g. [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files)), and then save the resulting URL into the user profile.